# Pass data from one worksheet to another in multiple one-dimensional arrays

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am trying to:

1. Take ranges of data from the first worksheet in a workbook and pass these into multiple one-dimensional arrays.
2. Output values from those arrays into the second worksheet in the same workbook.

Here are my issues:

The macro will only output all values from an array into Worksheet 2 if Worksheet 1 is the active sheet. If worksheet 2 is active there is no output.

Further, when I output LBound and UBound to check array size they come up as 1 for both, when it should be 1 to 40.

Finally, if I try to output the first value from an array, I get an "Out of Range" error.

Here is the code:

```
Sub M1_Run()

 ' Turns off screen updating and workbook calculations
 'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

 ' Clears any previous values from output sheet
 Worksheets(2).Range("A10:BZ50011").Clear

 ' Declares Variables to Use
 Dim rando As Double
 Dim runNum As Integer

 With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    ' Declare an array to hold a variable number of values
    Dim RevExpFV() As Variant
    Dim RevExpBase() As Variant
    Dim RevExpDist() As Variant
    Dim RevExpMin() As Variant
    Dim RevExpMax() As Variant
    Dim RevExpMean() As Variant
    Dim RevExpSD() As Variant

    ' Read values into arrays
    RevExpFV = Range("AG3:BT3")
    RevExpBase = Range("AG5:BT5")
    RevExpDist = Range("AG6:BT6")
    RevExpMin = Range("AG8:BT8")
    RevExpMax = Range("AG9:BT9")
    RevExpMean = Range("AG11:BT11")
    RevExpSD = Range("AG12:BT12")

    ' Test Output
    'Range("AF21:BS21") = RevExpDist

 End With

 ' Test Outputs
 ' Worksheets(1).Range("AF20:BS20") = RevExpDist
 Worksheets(2).Range("A10:AN10") = RevExpDist
 Worksheets(2).Range("A11") = LBound(RevExpDist)
 Worksheets(2).Range("B11") = UBound(RevExpDist)

 ' Script out of range error
 'Worksheets(2).Range("A12") = RevExpDist(1)

End Sub
```

I appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take for instance the lines which say:

```
Dim RevExpFV() As Variant
RevExpFV = Range("AG3:BT3")
```

You are populating the `Variant` array with a 1 row x 40 column range.  Therefore the array is dimensioned to be `1 To 1, 1 To 40`.

If you want to make the array one-dimensional, you will need to use the Transpose function (twice):

```
RevExpFV = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range("AG3:BT3")))
```

This will create a one-dimensional array of size `1 To 40`.

---

The reason that your code only works when `Worksheets(1)` is active is that the `Range` object defaults to referring to the active sheet.  So a statement such as

```
 RevExpFV = Range("AG3:BT3")
```

says populate the array `RevExpFV` with the `Value` (default property) of a `Range` on the active sheet.

You should always (unless you **know** that you want to use the Activesheet) specify which sheet you are referring to when using `Range`, `Cells`, `Rows`, etc, e.g.

```
 RevExpFV = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("AG3:BT3")
```

Because that piece of code is within a `With` block, that line can be simplified to

```
 RevExpFV = .Range("AG3:BT3")
```

(Note that a `With` statement is purely a coding shortcut method - it does not magically make the mentioned object "active" - it simply allows you, within a `With object` block, to type `.` instead of `object.`)

---

Based on feedback in chat, it appears that it isn't commonly known that an easy way to get a one-dimensional array from data which is stored in a column is to do a Transpose of the data, e.g.

```
 Dim myArray As Variant
 myArray = Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A30").Value)
```

And to get a one-dimensional array from data which is stored in a row (as in this question) you would do two Transposes of the data e.g.

```
 Dim myArray As Variant
 myArray = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range("A1:J1").Value)
```

Although this behaviour seems "weird", Excel itself often seems weird.

Comment: Are you sure about this?  The Transform twice does not work for me.  It is still two dimensional after two transforms.

Comment: 1 To 40, 1 To 1 is not one dimensional, it is a two dimensional table where one dimension is limited to one, i.e. a vector.

Comment: nope, still two dimensional, looking at my locals window.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132130/discussion-between-s-meaden-and-yowe3k).

Comment: Ah, ok. That explains a lot of the issues I was having. I didn't realize using columns defines it as multi-dimensional. I'm going to take another crack at it and update the question.

Comment: Hmm... All I get is the first value in the range repeated throughout the entire array. For instance one array has "Variable" and "Fixed" as possible values, but the array only outputs 40x "Variable" values down the entire column. If I change the first value to "Fixed" I get 40x "Fixed" I'll try just transposing it in Excel and picking that up.

Still having the trouble where I can only get the Array output on Sheet 2 if Sheet 1 is active. U and L Bound always outputs though...

Comment: @Matt "outputs 40x "Variable" values down the entire column" - your posted code shows you outputting to a row - if you are instead outputting to a column you will need to do something like `Worksheets(1).Range("AF20:AF59") = Application.Transpose(RevExpDist)`.  A `1 To 40` array is treated as if it is a `1 To 1, 1 To 40` array, i.e. 1 row x 40 columns.

Comment: There we go! That works! 

Any ideas on the Active sheet issue? I might just have to have references to the data in sheet 2 and pull from that. It will show bounds but no Array data unless sheet 1 is active while Macro is running.

Comment: Qualify your Ranges with a worksheet prefix. Use the codeName - it's more robust than numerical or nominal inddex of the Worksheets collection. Using Range("A1") just takes the range A1 from whatever worksheet is active. Sheet1.Range("A1") takes A1 from Sheet1 specifically

Comment: @YowE3K , nice tip about the 1D array thing.

Comment: @matt - See my latest edit to the answer - I suspect you didn't understand the purpose of the `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)` part of your code.

Comment: Ok, so I was missing a period before range.

Answer (score 0):

For a given two dimension range such as that arrived at using the Range() method...

Lbound(range,1) gives lower bound for rows, Lbound(range,2) gives lower bound for columns.   Ubound(range,1) gives upper bound for rows,  Ubound(range,2) gives upper bound for columns.    Lbound(range) defaults to the same as Lbound(range,1).

Comment: I need to add in transpose and see if that fixes the problem with outputs in worksheet 2 only working if worksheet 1 is active. Got a crying infant right now though.